# How to show AlertDialog from ScheduledExecutor?

Tags: android

I want to set up a scheduler and show a popup after a predefined time.

In the following example, the Log "scheduled alert" is printed once, but the alert dialog is never shown.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             //...
             initAlert(this);
        }

        private void initAlert(Activity activity) {
            final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
            executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  Log.i("app", "scheduled alert");

                  new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .setTitle("test")
                    .setMessage("lorep")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Log.i("app", "ok clicked");
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .create()
                    .show();
                }
            }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
}
```

The initialization is inside the main activity.

Why is the dialog not shown?

If I add a button to my view, and link the alert dialog explicit to that button click, it works. So the dialog code in general should be fine.

Comment: does it really compile? ins't the `this` in `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` the instance of Runnable?

Comment: Try to show alert in activity.runOnUiThread

Comment: @lelloman yes. This does not compile

Comment: as it's been point out, you should run it in the UI thread

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the `AppCompatActivity` to show the alert. Updated above. But still the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem of your code is that you're trying to show the Dialog not from the UI thread.

if all you need is to delay the display of the dialog by 10 seconds, and that would be it, you can use a `Handler`

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable showDialogRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("test")
                .setMessage("lorep")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Log.i("app", "ok clicked");
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
};
```

and post it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handler.postDelayed(showDialogRunnable, 10000);
...
```

if you want to cancel the scheduled execution you can call

```
handler.removeCallbacks(showDialogRunnable);
```

the thing is, if you don't pass `Looper` in the constuctor, the `Handler` with use the `Looper` associated with the `Thread` where the constructor is being called, in this case it would be the UI thread

**update**

if you want to keep your activity cleaner, you could create another class that implements that Runnable, for example

```
public class AlertDialogShower implements Runnable {
    private Context context;

    public AlertDialogShower(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("test")
                .setMessage("lorep")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Log.i("app", "ok clicked");
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}
```

and then instantiate it in your activity

```
private final Runnable showDialogRunnable = new AlertDialogShower(this);
```

Comment: How could I extract the `AlertDialog` definition in its own class? I there cannot call `MainActivity.this`...

Comment: you can use MainActivity.this from there, handler and showDialogRunnable are fields of MainActivity class

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to keep my `MainActivity` class clean and move the `showDialogRunnable` field outside of that class, as well as the alert dialog builder? Apart from it, the code works as expected, thanks!

Comment: you can create a class that implement Runnable and instantiate that instead of an anonymous one, i updated the answer with a sample

Answer (score 1):

```
private void initAlert() {
    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("app", "scheduled alert");
            YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("test")
                            .setMessage("lorep")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    Log.i("app", "ok clicked");
                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Hm, wrapping a `Runnable` inside a `Runnable` inside a scheduler just to show an async alert feels kind of strange. Though it works.

Comment: this is the solution, you can always declare the Runnable as a field of the activity